# How to use render a view in jquery Fancy Box Pop up

Tags: php, jquery, yii, fancybox

Am   working on YII project, I want to render an html form view in a pop up using fancy box pop up on clicking a  link.How can this be done ? I have tried fancy box extension but its not working..KIndly redirect me how can i implement this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl . '/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css'); 
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl . "/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js",  CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Include the files in the action you want and the controller you want

I like to put the code and css directly in my theme folder.

Then, you build your own js with `$(document).ready(function(){$('.myfancyboxlinks').fancybox(););`

the link should look like `<a class="myfancyboxlinks" href="/ajax/fancybox">Open Fancybox!</a>`

I also like having an AjaxController.php with a method like this:

```
public function actionFancybox()
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        //do stuff here
        // ............
        $this->layout = '//path/to/fancybox/layout';
        $this->render("myfancyboxview");
    }
}
```

Then, you can do anything you want in /views/ajax/myfancyboxview

Answer (score 1):

try this:

put

`<a href="link to your partially rendered page" id="fancybox-trigger">something</a>`

in your view, where needed.

in some other place (should be the same view):

```
$config = array( 
    'scrolling' => 'no', 
    'titleShow' => false,
    'overlayColor' => '#000',
    'padding' => '0',
    'showCloseButton' => false,
    'onClosed'=>'',
// change this as you need
);

$this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array('target'=>'#fancybox-trigger', 'config'=>$config));
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it when downloading the yii fancybox extension (you have to add it to protected/extensions to use it). This is how I ended up doing it as I'm trying to learn and take advantage of the way yii does things.